# How to migrate Database (from MSSQL Server to MySQL) having user defined data types

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to migrate an MSSQL Server database into a MySQL database. However, the MSSQL Server database has user-defined data types (which are not compatible with MySQL)

I have already tried using MySQL Workbench migration wizard but it does not work. It gives the following error:

> "ERROR: Migrate Selected Objects: AttributeError("'NoneType' object
>   has no attribute 'numericPrecision'"): error calling Python module
>   function DbMssqlMigration.migrateCatalog"

After doing some research, I found out the error is due to having some user-defined data types.

I have also tried manually creating my own code to extract the MSSQL Server Definitions (on Eclipse using JAVA) and changing them to be compatible with MySQL, it worked but my database is really big, the code will run for several days to finish (which is not very feasible).

Comment: MySQL does not support user defined types, so you will need to re-implement this portion of your code.

Comment: That's what I did. I extracted the definitions from the MSSQL Server database and re-creating them in a way to become compatible with MySQL. However it is taking days to copy the values and data from the MSSQL Server since the data is huge. 
I was wondering if there is an alternative solution to migrate when you have user-defined data types.

Comment: I might suggest doing the conversion in SQL Server and then just moving the resulting table over.